# .equals() method not working with multi dimensional arrays

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter the Item number of what is to be changed");
        String itemNO = in.next();

        for (int i = 0; i<NewItem.itemArray.length; i++)
        {
            String value = NewItem.itemArray[i][3];

            if(value.equals(itemNO))
            {
                //Rest of the code here
            }
}
```

When running the program, it throws an exception at "if(value.equals(itemNO))". This is the error it shows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DeleteItem.deleteItem(DeleteItem.java:34)
    at EditItemDetails.editItem(EditItemDetails.java:25)
    at CD_Universe.editItemDetailsActions(CD_Universe.java:84)
    at CD_Universe.main(CD_Universe.java:109)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` can still be null in your code, and therefore attempting to invoke `equals()` on it will throw an exception. Just because you are able to iterate over given element does not mean it has been initialized. I assume you have created an array of given size, but certain elements of that array have never been assigned a value.

You may fix this by populating the elements or adding a null check: `if (value != null)`...

In Java, only arrays of primitives are initialized with default values (since primitive type cannot be `null`. Arrays of reference types will not have their values initialized.